# Playframework: How do you upload to the tmp folder?

Tags: playframework

I'm following along with Plays! documentation on uploading files. For some reason when using `"/tmp/picture.jpg"`, my file does not get uploaded to my tmp folder but if I link to it like such `/Users/Me/Sites/play-app/tmp/picture.jpg`, then it gets uploaded.

So how can I upload files to the tmp folder without giving the that long path? (because I will deploy it soon and the path with not match)

Comment: Maybe is related with writing permissions into the /tmp/ folder? When you wanna link to the tmp folder inside the Play project (/Users/Me/Sites/play-app/tmp/) you should use "tmp/picture.jpg" instead of "/tmp/picture.jpg"

Comment: @DidacMontero you're absolutely right. "tmp/picture.jpg" works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are looking for a way to get the absolute path of your Play application. Try this (if you are using Scala):

```
import play.api.Play
val playroot = Play.application().path().getPath()
val filename = playroot + "/tmp/picture.jpg"
```

Or, if you are using Java:

```
import play.*;
String playroot = Play.application().path().getPath();
String filename = playroot + "/tmp/picture.jpg";
```